# Inheritance in Python: "TypeError: run() takes no arguments (2 given)"

Tags: python, inheritance, overwrite

I see other topics similar to this one, but not really what I need.

I have a class named "Base" where there calls for several methods. At the end of it is its own "run":

```
class BaseComponent(OSUtils):

    def __init__(self, cpio):
        OSUtils.__init__(self, cpio.logger)
        self.io = cpio

    def debug(self, msg):
        print("[Debug] %s" % msg)
        self.logger.debug(msg)

    def start(self, debug=False):

        try:
            self.info("--- Running %s:" % self.__class__.__name__)
            print self.__class__.__name__
            self.run(debug)

    def run(debug=False):
        component = BaseComp(cpio.ComponentIO())
        component.start(debug)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Testing")
```

I have another class, called "BaseComp" that extends "Base" with methods specific for a given need, on it there is a "run" method that must be rewritten and at the end of it the "run" of the class itself:

```
import dummy.io as cpio
class BaseComp(Base):

   def __init__(self, cpio):
       Base.__init__(self, cpio)
       self.io = cpio

   def run(self, debug=False):
       #this method will be rewritten latter
       #no matter what goes below
       #
       msg="blahblahblah"
       Exception(msg)

def run(debug=False):
    component = BaseComp(cpio.ComponentIO())
    component.start(debug)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Testing")
```

This class is extended by another one called Hello. Hello rewrites the method "run" of BaseComp and also has its own "run" at the end. In this run there is a call to "component.start(debug)

```
from base_components import BaseComp
import dummy.io as cpio
class Hello(BaseComp):

    def run(self, debug=True):
        print "Begin"
        msg="hello world"
        print "End"

def run(debug=True):
    component = Hello(cpio.ComponentIO())
    component.start(debug)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Testing Start")
    run(debug = True)
    print("Test End")
```

component.start(debug) calls the method start from the first class ("Base")

However when this call is made I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/components/comp1/__init__.py", line 166, in run component.start()
  File "/home/user/directory/apps/Base.py", line 58, in start self.run(debug)  ***** this is in the start method 
TypeError: run() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

I don't know what is causing the error. I believe it may be related with so many "run" methods being called

This is driving me crazy because I am a bit lost in the whole inheritance schema

Any help would be wonderfull

thks

Comment: So where is `Base`? You have a `BaseComponent` here instead. The code you posted is not enough to reproduce your problem (it won't show the issue as all your `run()` methods have `self` and `debug` arguments). Are you sure you haven't missed a component somewhere, or did something wrong with the indentation of a `run` function?

Comment: Is this supposed to be some sort of thread?

Comment: You are right Martijn. Sorry for the typo. The first class at the top is called "Base" and not "BaseComponent"

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply have an indentation error. In the base file, the `run` function is indented inside the class, so is being called as the `run` *method*; however it does not accept the automatic `self` parameter, hence the error.

You might find it useful to rename the functions so that they don't share a name with the methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have this

```
class SomeClass(object):
   def somefunc():
      print 'somefunc in SomeClass'
```

because the python class method receives 'self' by default. 
Attempting to call somefunc from a class instance would yield

```
TypeError: somefunc() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

You can add self

```
class SomeClass(object):
   def somefunc(self):
      print 'somefunc in SomeClass'
```

Or, if you don't need or want 'self' you can either make it a top level function (not a class function) or make it a staticmethod

```
class SomeClass(object):
   @staticmethod
   def somefunc():
      print 'somefunc in SomeClass'
```

This is what you have in your BaseComponent class' run method.

Answer (score 0):

From your error printout it appears you're calling a run() method defined in OSUtils (??). Like Wyrmwood mentioned, the run method defined in your BaseComponent class should either have a self argument or the @staticmethod decorator.

Ex.

```
class BaseComponent(OSUtils):
    def run(self, debug=False):
        ...
```

or

```
class BaseComponent(OSUtils):
    @staticmethod
    def run(debug=False):
        ...
```